# Concatenate column based on id and date using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been asked to concatenate Cmnts based on id and date. I tried writing a macro but my macro concatenate cmnts only based on ID,

```
id      Sno Date        Cnt Comnts

1299    001 4/08/2016   1   A
1302    001 4/08/2016   1   B
1642    001 10/08/2015  1   C.
1642    001 14/08/2015  1   D
1642    001 21/12/2015  1   1.
1642    001 21/12/2015  2   2.
1642    001 16/02/2016  1   3.
1642    001 8/04/2016   1   T
1644    001 25/09/2015  1   M
1747    001 13/09/2016  1   J
1748    001 13/09/2016  1   O
1751    001 3/03/2015   1   P
```

O/P

```
id      Sno Date        Cnt Comnts

1299    001 4/08/2016   1   A
1302    001 4/08/2016   1   B
1642    001 10/08/2015  1   C.
1642    001 14/08/2015  1   D
1642    001 21/12/2015  1   1. 2.
1642    001 16/02/2016  1   3.
1642    001 8/04/2016   1   T
1644    001 25/09/2015  1   M
1747    001 13/09/2016  1   J
1748    001 13/09/2016  1   O
1751    001 3/03/2015   1   P
```

My macro below Concatenate the comments only based on ID.
How can i modify it to concatenate comments based on ID and date

Macro:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim a, c, i As Long, n As Long
    With Range("a1").CurrentRegion
        a = .Value
        c = .Value2
        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1) And UBound(c, 1)
                If Not .exists(a(i, 1)) And Not .exists(c(i, 1)) Then
                    n = n + 1
                    a(n, 1) = a(i, 1)
                    c(n, 1) = c(i, 1)
                    a(n, 2) = a(i, 2)
                     c(n, 2) = c(i, 2)
                    a(n, 3) = a(i, 3)
                    c(n, 3) = c(i, 3)
                     a(n, 4) = a(i, 4)
                       c(n, 4) = c(i, 4)
                      a(n, 5) = a(i, 5)
                      c(n, 5) = c(i, 5)
                    .Item(a(i, 1)) = n
                    .Item(c(i, 1)) = n
                Else
                    a(.Item(a(i, 1)), 5) = a(.Item(a(i, 1)), 5) & " " & a(i, 5)
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1).Resize(n).Value = a
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain the question a little better please. 
i.e. concatenate comments with what?
is there a condition, i.e. if id=something and date=something concatenate comment with id... something like this..
I'm thinking you can solve this with a simple worksheet function
Your code is pretty confusing, I would suggest a different approach

Comment: Looks like you're also deleting lines as well?  Where is the second `1642 12/12/15` line?  Are the lines always sorted by id and date?

Comment: Hi, I have to Concatenate comnts based on id and date. ie For same id and date if there are multiple rows comnts have to be concatenated resulting in  single row

Comment: The above macro i tried concatenates comnts only based on id. I need it to be modified adding date condition as well

Comment: The data may or may not be sorted. We are reusing this macro for many sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the macro below is one easy way to group some secords (with same 2 conditions) and concatenate the specific value (comments).

```
Sub Concatenate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim lrw As Integer
Dim rgn As Range

lrw = ActiveSheet().Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row                                     'last row of your table
Set rgn = Range("A1:E" & lrw)
rgn.Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Foglio1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Foglio1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A13") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers   '1th order by ID
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Foglio1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C13") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal          '2th order by date
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Foglio1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D2:D13") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal          '3th order by cnt
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Foglio1").Sort
    .SetRange rgn
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
    For i = 2 To lrw
        x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("E2:E" & lrw), "*", Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("A2:A" & lrw), Cells(i, 1), Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("C2:C" & lrw), Cells(i, 3))
        If x > 1 Then
            cmnts = Cells(i, 5)
          For J = 1 To x - 1
          cmnts = cmnts & " " & Cells(i + J, 5)
            Rows(i + J).Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Next J
            Cells(i, 5) = cmnts
        End If
     Next i
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Foglio1").Sort
    .SetRange rgn
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Enter below Array Formula in G2  (If you are using Excel 2016)

```
{=CONCAT(IF($A$3:$A$14&$C$3:$C$14=G3&H3,$E$3:$E$14&" ","")}
```

you will get your result.

For earlier versions, we need to create UDF

```
{=ConcatUDF(IF($C$3:$C$14&$A$3:$A$14=H3&G3,$E$3:$E$14,"")," ")}
```

Below is the code for UDF

```
Function ConcatUDF(rng() As Variant, ByVal delim As String) As String
Dim a, i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(rng, 1)
    If rng(i, 1) <> "" Then
    ConcatUDF = ConcatUDF & _
        IIf(ConcatUDF = "", "", delim) & rng(i, 1)
    End If
Next
End Function
```

and we will get the result.

[image]

Comment: After selecting range and delimiter. Am i missing something?

Comment: Im using Excel 2010

Comment: use UDF & hit ALT + SHIFT + ENTER to make an array formula